# TS2614: Module has no exported member 'NextHandleFunction'

Tags: node.js, typescript, nodes, node-modules, tsoa

```
Error:
node_modules/@types/body-parser/index.d.ts:14:10 - error TS2614: Module '"../../../src/connect"' has no exported member 'NextHandleFunction'. Did you mean to use 'import NextHandleFunction from "../../../src/connect"' instead?  14 import { NextHandleFunction } from 'connect';
```

I'm trying to use typescript into my nodejs project instead of javascript. I have followed a few tutorials and looked into some Github repositories, even though I'm getting this weird while compiling, but my server is getting started.

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

type TInput = {
  db: string;
}
export default ({db}: TInput) => {
  
  const connect = () => {
    mongoose
      .connect(
        db,
        { useNewUrlParser: true }
      )
      .then(() => {
        return console.info(`Successfully connected to ${db}`);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error connecting to database: ', error);
        return process.exit(1);
      });
  };
  connect();

  mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', connect);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

try this compiler option inside tsconfig.json

```
  "skipLibCheck": true,
```